# spresense-binaries-vX.Y.Z.zip ダウンロードに関して

Tags: spresense

Spresense SDK スタートガイド (CLI 版)の開発環境を構築しているのですが、
§3. ブートローダーのインストール
で

> ZIP ファイルのダウンロード
>
> Download URL に記載されているリンクを開き ZIP ファイルをダウンロードします。

という記載がありますが、リンクはどれでしょうか？

とりあえず、コマンドラインでcurlが私の環境では使えないので、wgetで以下のダウンロードでそれなりのサイズのzipファイルがダウンロードできましたが、

> $ wget https://developer.sony.com/file/download/spresense-binaries-vX.Y.Z.zip

ダウンロードしたファイルは、以下のようにzip圧縮ファイルでは無いようです。
該当ファイルをどのようにダウンロードしたら良いか教えてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

[マニュアル](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ja.html#_%E3%83%96%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB) に記載のファイル名 "spresense-binaries-vX.Y.Z.zip" は**仮**のものですので、このまま wget でダウンロードしても、中身は恐らく (Page Not Foundな) HTMLファイルになってしまっているはずです。
(`file spresense-binaries-vX.Y.Z.zip` と実行してみてください)

実際には、`config.py` や `flash.sh` などのバッチファイルを実行したときに表示されるURLを確認する必要があります。

> 適切なバージョンのブートローダーがインストールされていない場合、`spresense/sdk` ディレクトリの下で、 後述する `tools/config.py` 及び `tools/flash.sh` ツールを実行したときに次のような WARNING が表示されます。

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。私の日本語の読解力が無かったようです。「config.py や flash.sh などのバッチファイルを実行したときに表示されるURLを確認する必要があります。」と有りますが、具体的にどんな入力をしたら良いかをお教えください。

Comment: "$ ./tools/config.py examples/hello"  で圧縮ファイルを特定することが出来ました。かなり試行錯誤しましたが。。。( ..)φメモメモ